# Is there any published record for quantum mechanical version of double-slit experiment with & without disturbance?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment, interference

Can anybody provide the published record (journal papers) for the following experiment done actually in lab ?

> Young's double slit experiment with electrons or other particles
>   (other than photons) verifying that whenever attempt is made to find
>   out through which slit the particle has gone, the interference (which
>   was observed before disturbance) vanishes.

I guess, if the experiment has been done, it must has been done with single particle passing through one or the other slit one at a time i.e. source intensity is extremely low.

Comment: You've used the blockquote formatting - is that actually a quote from somewhere?

Comment: Not at all. I wanted to highlight the description of the experiment.